# Someone or something small yet capable of having big influence?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, synonyms

What is a word or phrase that means a person or thing which is quite small yet capable of having big **influence** and impact on society?

Comment: You need to tell us more if you want the right word, as per single word requests guidelines.

Comment: For a phrase, it could be *casting a long shadow*.

Comment: @MatthewRead I think *casting a long shadow* nails the request for some"thing like "He may be small, but he casts a long shadow." You should make that an answer (with some supporting documentation).

Comment: OP requests the single word, I don`t have any. but in case it could be usefull, there are idioms, that represent this meaning. _Gutta cavat lapidem_ (Latin for _The drop excavates the stone_), _One spoonful of tar spoils a barrel of honey_ (not that close)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small thing: a certain **catalyst** for social development

> Catalysis is the increase in the rate of a chemical reaction due to
>   the participation of an additional substance called a catalyst.
>   With a catalyst, reactions occur faster and with less energy. Because
>   catalysts are not consumed, they are recycled. Often only **tiny amounts**
>   are required.
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalysis)

E.g., in context:

> [Critical Strategies for Social Research](https://books.google.ca/books?id=0ifquwWtU2oC&pg=PA278&dq=%22catalyst%20for%20social%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iSsUVd-QJKnbsATgnYDICw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22catalyst%20for%20social%22&f=false) - Page 278 William K.
>   Carroll - 2004
>
> ... and Leslie Brown, who, in our third reading, introduce community
>   action research (CAR) as a value-based approach to research that
>   strives to promote individual self-discovery, to build communities,
>   and to **act as a catalyst for social change.**

And, of course, **lever.**

> [Higher Education for Women in Postwar America, 1945–1965](https://books.google.ca/books?id=BXsD1V6sS0EC&pg=PT156&dq=%22lever%20for%20social%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sS0UVbfTOoq0sATa8oCQAw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22lever%20for%20social%22&f=false) Linda
>   Eisenmann - 2010
>
> Third was a new awareness of education as potential **[ly]** **a lever for social**
>   **change**.

Comment: Good one! Accurate and applicable to people and things.

Comment: Just my thoughts, but the point of catalysts is that they are not doing anything themselves. For example if I understand the contextual quote correctly the idea is that the research itself doesn't change anything, but that it empowers those that will cause the social change.

Comment: @DavidMulder - while this may be true in chemistry/biochemistry, that is not how the word is understood in general. A single person can be a catalyst for great change: "Dr. King was a *catalyst* for transformative societal changes." - pcc.edu

Answer (score 7):

*David.*

David was a young shepherd with a sling and 5 smooth stones who pitted himself against a gigantic Philistine who was fully armed for battle. Yet he brought the giant down with one stone (saving the others for the giant's brothers.)

> - But we've known O'Brien is a fighter since back in the day, when he was the David to Jay Leno's Goliath. [Boston Globe]
> - Apple, for a long time, was the David to Microsoft’s Goliath. ...It was the iPod that first signaled a change in this arrangement. At the close of Wednesday’s trading, Apple was valued at $222 billion, while Microsoft was worth $219 billion....

If it's a scenario like the above, it will be understood.

Comment: That's what I was thinking...or for full analogy..."a David vs. Goliath" scenario.

Comment: 'David' is certainly an example of 'a thing which is small yet has a big influence on the giant', but is the word 'David' a commonly recognised noun for such a thing?

Comment: @MarvMills When properly used? Definitely. And otherwise it might need more contextualization for example using the full analogy as proposed by Kristina.

Comment: @DavidMulder - I agree that it needs to be put into context to make sense to the reader.

Comment: my first thought it was. but one has to make an expression of it, to make the reference to certain biblical story more clear, i guess.
i see @tom shared the same opinion

Answer (score 0):

*[Seminal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/seminal)*:

> adjective
>
> 1.0 (Of a work, event, moment, or figure) strongly influencing later developments:
>
> 2.0 Of, relating to, or denoting semen.
>
> 2.1 Botany Of, relating to, or derived from the seed of a plant.
>
> ODO

The meaning of *seminal* is ***big influence***, the connotation is *small*.

*With just ten sentences uttered over a mere two-and-a-half minutes, Abraham Lincoln delivered his **seminal** Gettysburg Address that continues to shape politics into the twenty-first century.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one word can convey all of the meaning you want. - 'Small, but effective' - or something that  'punches above its weight' or 'disproportionately significant' or 'hugely influential' or 'surprisingly important' or 'unexpectedly significant' or 'trend-setting' - hope these expressions may be useful.

Another overused expression that might be useful if 'game-changer'.