# What is an English term for "an event that triggers a chain of events, ultimately to downfall"?

Tags: terminology, greek, shakespeare, rhetorical-devices

I'm trying to incorporate more technical literary terms into my Macbeth revision for my upcoming exam. I've discovered terms such as Hamartia, Catharsis, Peripeteia, etc.

What would be a good word to describe the meeting between the witches and Macbeth in Act 1, Scene 3? Something that closely means "an event that triggers a chain of events, ultimately leading to downfall".

Comment: Is it foreshadowing?

Comment: This might be better suited for our sister site, [[Literature.SE]] .

Comment: This isn't an answer, but: I would avoid trying to incorporate more technical literary terms purely to do better on an exam; that strategy is unlikely to work.

Comment: @alphabet I know, but I've been analysing some of my friends' papers (who get high grades) and something that was common was their use of context and greek ideologies. I just want to make sure that I seem like I know what I'm talking about and get all the marks possible.

Comment: @Haroon I don't think that the verbiage per se was what got them high marks. I think that they got high marks for understanding literary theory, which had the side effect of giving them a broader vocabulary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word/phrase that means a series of problems of increasing severity caused by a small error](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256232/word-phrase-that-means-a-series-of-problems-of-increasing-severity-caused-by-a-s) ('snowball effect'; 'domino effect', 'cascading failure' ...) Or [someone-or-something-small-yet-capable-of-having-big-influence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235767/someone-or-something-small-yet-capable-of-having-big-influence/235778#235778) ('catalyst' ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meeting between the witches and Macbeth in Act 1, Scene 3 could be described as a "**catalyst**" for the chain of events that ultimately leads to Macbeth's downfall. A **catalyst** is an event or influence that sets off a series of actions or changes. In this case, the witches' prophecy and Macbeth's ambition set off a series of actions and changes leading to his downfall.

Some other terms are:
**Incitement**: something that provokes or stirs up a particular feeling or response
**Stimulus**: something that causes a particular reaction or response
**Trigger**: something that initiates a process or reaction
**Initiator**: something that starts or causes a process or event to begin.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 2):

"The first domino"

[Domino effect.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_effect)

> The domino effect can easily be visualized by placing a row of dominoes upright, each separated by a small distance. Upon pushing the first domino, the next domino in line will be knocked over, and so on, thus firing a linear chain in which each domino's fall is triggered by the domino immediately preceding it.

Examples:

[In Search of the First Domino: The Credit Crisis of 1772-1773 in a Global History Perspective](https://globalhistory.org.uk/2021/05/in-search-of-the-first-domino/)

[What was the very first domino in the events that led to the great recession?](https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-very-first-domino-in-the-events-that-led-to-the-great-recession)

[The Courage of the First Domino](https://bryanhendley.medium.com/the-courage-of-the-first-domino-2bcae043039d)

Comment: Is this a "technical literary term" though?

Comment: Also _snowball_.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely be able to incorporate it in my essay.